# The Code's output is its gonna show you how many score been input and will compute the average with 4 methods

Tags: c#

Good evening mam/sir,

Is it okay if you can help me with my C# activity ?

The code will show how many scores you inputted and the average score using the sentinel and condition statement, The personal information will show based on what you Inputted.

Enter a Score (0-100) :
Enter a number LESS than 0 to STOP:

```
enter code here
```

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;
using System.Transactions;

namespace MidExam
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String Name, Add, Sec, bDay, Motto, cNum;
            
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your information: ");

            Console.Write("Name           : ");
            Name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Section        : ");
            Sec = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Address        : ");
            Add = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Contact Number : ");
            cNum = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Birthday       : ");
            bDay = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Motto          : ");
            Motto = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("********************         LABORATORY               ********************");
            Console.WriteLine("Name is            : {0}", Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Section is         : {0}", Sec);
            Console.WriteLine("Address is          : {0}", Add);
            Console.WriteLine("Contact Number is  : {0}", cNum);
            Console.WriteLine("Birthday is        : {0}", bDay);
            Console.WriteLine("Motto is           : {0}", Motto);
            Console.WriteLine("*****************************************************************************************"+"\n\n");

           
            Console.Write("To begin, press any key!...");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();

            getInput();
            Console.ReadKey();
            
        }
        public static void getInput()
        {
            String inValue = "";
            int sum = 0, intValue ;

            Console.Write("Please enter a score 0 - 100:");
            inValue = Console.ReadLine();

            while (inValue == "0-100")
            {
                if (int.TryParse(inValue, out intValue) == false)
                {
                    Console.Write("Enter a number LESS than 0 to STOP entering scores ");
                }
                sum += intValue;
                Console.Write("Please enter a score 0 - 100:");
                inValue = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine("Number of scores entered: {0}", sum);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
       static void Display Info() {

Total Scores Input:
Average of Scores:

Press Y if you want to Input again and Any other letters if NO!
}

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: This seems to be a slightly better question than this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63860066/helphelphelphelphelp

Comment: Have you considered using some sort of collection to capture the input and calculate the average? 

Comment: Question is not clear

Answer (score 1):

First you need to fix the while loop:

```
public static void getInput()
{
   String inValue = "";
   int sum = 0, intValue ;       
   while (true)
   {
         Console.Write("Please enter a score 0 - 100:");
         inValue = Console.ReadLine();

         if (int.TryParse(inValue, out intValue) == false)
         {
             Console.Write("Enter a number LESS than 0 to STOP entering scores ");
              continue; // skips the rest of the lines and starts the next iteration
          }
          if (intValue < 0) break; // exits the loop 

          sum += intValue;
   }
            
   Console.WriteLine("Number of scores entered: {0}", sum);
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Then,  try to keep a variable to count how many valid inputs the user has entered.

The average is the `sum/count` of the two variables you have.

PS: I gave part of the answer to address items that I assumed you didn't know and described the rest of the logic, to help you tackle the problem yourself.

Comment: I tried to help as best I could, without giving him the entire answer, to help a fellow guy grow. At least he tried to tackle it a bit.

Comment: OK, I retracted my comment. However I still believe that here we are on a borderline between teaching to fish and giving the fish.

Comment: Agreed! It would be better researched than given cooked, but still...

Comment: Total Scores Input:7 // Based on how many scores you have inputted                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Average of Scores:86% // Based on the average of the 7 scores you input